Как отправить данные с telegram webapp на бекенд?
Написал бота на aiogram 3, начал писать webapp для него и у меня должен быть в центре экрана кликер, то есть пользовать нажимает кнопку и мне на сервер должен прилетать его id, используя встроенную функцию sendData из скрипта телеграмм, просто закрывается приложение с сообщением о том, что данные были перенаправлены боту, а мне нужно, чтобы человек мог нажимать кнопку сколько угодно раз, а приложение не закрывалось(подобие фармилок всяких крипто монет). Вопрос в том, что как мне нужно реализовать способ отправки в код некоторых данных при нажатии кнопки, так как senddata не подходит

Попробуй реализовать через inline кнопку либо MenuButton. Ты сможешь при каждом нажатии на кликер брать данные о пользователе через метод initData и отправляя их себе на сервер прописать нужную логику. Но если твой web-app открывается не через ReplyKeyboard ты не сможешь использовать метод sendData.
